# Can anyone give me a good example of This kind of situation about "What makes an object stateful"?

Tags: scala, object, stateful

I don't understand the meaning of this sentence (from [*Scala-Threading/Odersky/18-stateful-objects.txt line 88*](https://github.com/chrchang1/Scala-Threading/blob/master/Odersky/18-stateful-objects.txt)):

> **a class might be stateful** without defining or inheriting any vars **because it forwards method calls to other objects that have mutable state**.

Can anyone give me a good example of this kind of situation in Scala ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Account {
  private var balance = 0
  def getBalance = balance
  def deposit(amount: Int): Unit = balance += amount
}

class NoVarAccount {
  val account = new Account()
  def balance = account.getBalance
  def deposit(amount: Int) = account.deposit(amount)
}
```

Now, `NoVarAccount` doesn't have any `var` in it, but it is still stateful because it's forwarding calls to `Account` which is indeed stateful.

In fact, you don't have any guarantee that calling `balance` twice on the same object will get you the same result.

```
val account = new NoVarAccount()
account.balance // 0
account.deposit(42)
account.balance // 42
```

In this example, `account.balance` is not *referentially transparent*, i.e. you cannot replace `account.balance` with its return value, because it may vary.

Conversely, a stateless account would go as follows:

```
class StatelessAccount(val balance: Int = 0) {
  def deposit(amount: Int) = new StatelessAccount(balance + amount)
}
```

or even more idiomatically:

```
case class StatelessAccount(balance: Int = 0) {
  def deposit(amount: Int) = this.copy(balance = balance + amount))
}
```

In this case `balance` is referentially transparent:

```
val account = StatelessAccount()
account.balance // 0
val account2 = account.deposit(42)
account2.balance // 42
account.balance // still 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class FileWrapper(file : java.io.RandomAccessFile) {

  def isEmpty = file.read() < 0

  def next = file.read()
}
```

In the above example file maintains its own state but FileWrapper only forwards method calls to the file object.